# Almost every second an unexpected CacheInsert

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

On one of our production servers we can see a CacheInsert that occurs almost every second. The profiler says the the statement is encrypted, so we have no clue what's causing it.

Some side-effects:

- we can see that the SQLFT-log grows very rapidly and that the size of the Logs are 5Gb and up.
- it looks like 20% of CPU of the SQL-server is used for the CacheInserts
- in the query cache we can see following statement with a high usecount

```
(@p1 timestamp, @p2 timestamp)select top 2000 column fulltextkey as    k, column fulltextall, dst.docid , dst.ts  from [dbo].[TABLE] t WITH    (READPAST), [DATABASE].[sys].[fulltext_index_docidmap_2105058535] dm    WITH (READPAST),    [DATABASE].[sys].[fulltext_index_docidstatus_2105058535] dst WITH    (READPAST) where column fulltextkey = dm.ftkey and dm.docid =    dst.docid and dst.status = 0 and dst.ts > @p1 and dst.ts <= @p2 order    by dst.ts
```

Restarting the server solves the problem, but we would like to know why this is happening so we can prevent future performance problems.

Any idea?

Comment: Look at the spid with `sp_who`. Find out what service or application it is.